# Remote validation stopping submit button from saving data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using remote validation on a view and it works perfectly. The problem I have is that when I click on the submit button nothing happens and focus returns to the field that I have remote validation on - The form never gets submitted.

To set up remote validation I referred to this page - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx - not sure if there's anything more recent available.

If I remove `[Remote]` from the model it submits correctly.
What am I doing wrong ???

My model is

```
public class Doctor
{
    [Remote("checkEmployeeNumber", "Doctors")]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string DoctorSurname { get; set; }
    public string DoctorGivenName { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller

```
public ActionResult checkEmployeeNumber(string EmployeeNumber)
{
    if (EmployeeNumber == null)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    Doctor doctor = db.Doctors.Find(EmployeeNumber);
    if (doctor == null)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Doctor

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<h2>New Doctor Entry</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorSurname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorGivenName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorGivenName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorGivenName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I've also added the following to Web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking at a problem for 2 days I discover the solution 5 minutes after lodging a question! doh!

It seems that I was getting my double negatives confused.

In my controller where I've got true and false if you switch them around then it works as expected.

One thing I wasn't expecting is that remote validation seems be activated twice

1. When you leave the field
2. When you press the submit button on a form.

I wasn't expecting the submit button check.

Hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I also faced Same problem In my code...
I am using .net Core 3.1 MVC architecture

I have Following Scenarios in my code which you can relate to
1.I also have a form with Remote Validation in Model.
2.Submit button calls that Remote Validation On first Click then on second Click the form is posting.

So I found that I put an Id in my submit button like following

```
 <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit
 </button>
```

I Renamed the Id Of submit button to something else, and now it is Working, I kept Id on submit button because I need it for some on Click action of that button.

Hope I helped.