# Prevent .Net Core Remote Validation on form Submit event

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, model-validation, remote-validation

I have put a remote validation in Model Class,
And it triggered automatically on Sub event and it makes submit button to click twice! to actually work (submit).

in a nut shell
on Submit button

1. It calls remote validation method.
   2 It calls actual submit event.

This is similar questions, if anyone find answer please post here.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004600/remote-validation-stopping-submit-button-from-saving-data?answertab=active#tab-top) question has an answer which shows the exact same reserach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution it is because I gave submit button an id as id='submit', and after I changed it to something else., not it is working.